# React Native Android build, "ERROR: Could not get unknown property 'mergeResourcesProvider'"

Tags: javascript, react-native, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have upgraded my app with RN 0.59.3 and ever since I am receiving an error when building Android. iOS builds the application just fine.

Android studio

***ERROR: Could not get unknown property 'mergeResourcesProvider' for object of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.ApplicationVariantImpl.***

Console

```
error Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
error Command failed: ./gradlew app:installSabdebugDebug
```

I tried changing distributionUrl in android/app/gralde/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.propeties to

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.2-all.zip
```

and I upgraded build.gradle dependencies to these versions

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
    ...
}
```

Here is the whole document

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 27
        targetSdkVersion = 26
        androidMapsUtilsVersion = "0.5+"
        googlePlayServicesAuthVersion = "16.0.1"
    }

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
    }
}
```

And I'm setting these **app/build.gradle**

```
android {
      compileSdkVersion safeExtGet('compileSdkVersion', 28)
    buildToolsVersion safeExtGet('buildToolsVersion', '28.0.0')

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp"
        resValue "string", "build_config_package", "com.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 18
        multiDexEnabled true
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 24
        versionName "1.3.5"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
...
```

My package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-transform-remove-console": "^6.9.4",
    "formik": "^1.3.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.10",
    "moment": "^2.23.0",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.21",
    "native-base": "^2.8.1",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "0.59.3",
    ....
}
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.3",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.4.3",
    "babel-jest": "^24.7.0",
    "jest": "^24.7.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.53.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.3",
    "run-script-os": "~1.0.5"
  },
```

Also we're using scripts to build the different environments of the app with run-script-os, but I don't believe that is causing the problem.

I was also having an error of not being able to find Android sdk, but I resolved that with local.properties.

Cheers!

Comment: please follow this closed issue -- https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/issues/4757

Comment: tried it yesterday, didn't work for me, but thanks for noting

Comment: didn't work sadly

Answer (score 1):

In `gradle-wrapper.properties:` change `distributionUrl`

to

`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.1-all.zip`

And in root `build.gradle` file change gradle classpath to this:

`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'`

**Remove** `node_modules` and **npm install && react-native run-android** again.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit: WORKING VERSION**

I have upgraded my app with

```
   "react": "16.8.6",
   "react-native": "0.59.8"
```

**android/app/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.propeties**

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.1-all.zip
```

**android/build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
    ...
}
```

Here is the whole document

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 19
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
        appCompatVersion = "28.0.0"
        androidMapsUtilsVersion = "0.5+"

        googlePlayServicesAuthVersion = "16.0.1"
        googlePlayServicesBaseVersion = "16.1.0"
        googlePlayServicesLocationVersion = "16.0.0"
        googlePlayServicesPlacesVersion = "1.1.0"
        firebaseCoreVersion = "16.0.9"
        firebaseMessagingVersion = "18.0.0"
    }

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
        // maven {
        //     // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
        //     url "https://maven.google.com"
        // }
    }
}
```

**android/app/build.gradle**

```
android {
     compileSdkVersion safeExtGet('compileSdkVersion', 28)
    buildToolsVersion safeExtGet('buildToolsVersion', '28.0.0')

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sportjoe"
        resValue "string", "build_config_package", "com.myapp"
        minSdkVersion safeExtGet('minSdkVersion', 19)
        multiDexEnabled true
        targetSdkVersion safeExtGet( 'targetSdkVersion' , 28 )
        versionCode 34
        versionName "1.4.11"
        ndk {
            abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'
        }
    }
...
```

My **package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-transform-remove-console": "^6.9.4",
    "formik": "^1.5.4",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.25",
    "native-base": "^2.12.1",
    "react": "16.8.6",
    "react-native": "0.59.8"
    ....
}
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "24.8.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.1",
    "jest": "24.8.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.6",
    "run-script-os": "~1.0.5"
  },
```

Seems to work for me now, hope it helps!